# firebase, keep user signed in after exiting the app, swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Sorry if this is a repetative question but I have tried other people's answers here and none of the worked. I was to keep the user signed in after exiting my app. I am using email authentication and backend is Fire base. I tried implementing a function an app delegate but had no luck. any advice is appreciated.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let auth = Auth.auth()

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            auth.addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] (_, user) in
                if user != nil {
                    let vc = self?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Profile")
                    self?.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    //
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the relevant code, what you expect it to be doing, and why it doesn't work the way you expect.  Without that, people can only guess what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: I did add the code ^

Comment: "I had no luck" is not very concrete. If you put a breakpoint on `if user != nil {` and run the code in a debugger, does the breakpoint fire? If so, what is the value of `user` at that point? Note it may fire multiple times during application startup.

Comment: Why do you have app:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as a function within your viewDidAppear method?